# How to pass a NotresXspViewEntry as a ViewEntry into a Java class

Tags: xpages

In a repeat I'm showing a handful of documents from a view; the view datasource is bound to the repeat by passing the datasource defined at the page's xp:view level. The repeat defines a NotesXspViewEntry object ("Collection name") called "rowEntry".

Now I need to perform some simple manipulation to the document data shown inside the repeat; one of the tasks is to find out the current position of the entry within the view and then find out about the neighboring siblings of my current entry.

I tried to be brave and wrote my code as a java class, but am running into a problem at the first possible occasion:

my class constructor is looking like this:

```
public EntrySorter(ViewEntry veThis){
    this.veThis = veThis;
}
```

My SSJS code is like that:

```
var es = EntrySorter(rowEntry);
```

Obviously veThis is the right object because

```
System.out.println("DEBUG: NoteID = " + veThis.getNoteID());
```

is returning the correct NoteID. But asking for the entry's position returns `null`:

```
System.out.println("DEBUG: position in view = " + veThis.getPosition('.'));
```

Trying to do the same thing directly using SSJS is working just great. This here returns the correct position, e.g. inside a computed field:

```
rowEntry.getPosition('.');
```

Also `veThis.getParent()` is not returning a `ViewNavigator` object as it does in SSJS.

Question is: is this something that cannot be done the way I thought, or do I have to do some kind of manipulation to my viewEntry object before passing it into the Java object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, right now I solved this using a workaround by getting the `NotesDocument` object out of the `XspViewEntry`, then passing in the doc to my java code, then moving the ViewNav pointer to the right entry using `nav.gotoEntry(doc);` this appears to be working now; question still remains: is there really no way getting the "real" ViewEntry object out of the wrapped XSP version?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the API, it looks like you can call rowEntry.getViewEntry() to get the java ViewEntry object.

API for NotesXSPViewEntry:
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/XPagesExtAPI/8.5.2/com/ibm/xsp/model/domino/wrapped/DominoViewEntry.html

Comment: sounds promising, but trying to usesiad method I'm told it is not visible, and that I can't use it (I tried passing in the rowEntry as DominoViewEntry as well as AbstractDominoViewEntry); speaking of Java, I'm just a beginner so this might not be a real problem, but unfortunately it is for me...

Comment: Update to my previous comment: tried to perform getViewEntry() on the SSJS side instead of the Java side; this to the SSJS side results in an explicit runtime error: "[TypeError] Error calling method 'getViewEntry()' on an object of type 'NotesXspViewEntry [Static Java Wrapper, com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.AbstractDominoViewEntry]'"; looks as if there wasn't a proper way to use the method, or is it?

Comment: Yes.. Sorry. I reread the API, and I see now that getViewEntry is protected in the parent class, so it's not reachable in DominoViewEntry without java reflection tricks/reducing the JVM security restrictions. Your workaround might be the best workaround.